# Postgres: create foreign key relationship, getting 'Key is not present in table'?

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys

I am working in Postgres 9.1 and I want to create a foreign key relationship for two tables that don't currently have one.

These are my tables:

```
# \d frontend_item;
                                       Table "public.frontend_item"
      Column       |          Type           |                             Modifiers
-------------------+-------------------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
 id                | integer                 | not null default nextval('frontend_prescription_id_seq'::regclass)
 presentation_code | character varying(15)   | not null
 pct_code          | character varying(3)    | not null
Indexes:
    "frontend_item_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)

# \d frontend_pct;

   Column   |           Type           | Modifiers
------------+--------------------------+-----------
 code       | character varying(3)     | not null
Indexes:
    "frontend_pct_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (code)
    "frontend_pct_code_1df55e2c36c298b2_like" btree (code varchar_pattern_ops)
```

This is what I'm trying:

```
# ALTER TABLE frontend_item ADD CONSTRAINT pct_fk 
  FOREIGN KEY (pct_code) REFERENCES frontend_pct(code) ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  insert or update on table "frontend_item" violates 
        foreign key constraint "pct_fk"
DETAIL:  Key (pct_code)=(5HQ) is not present in table "frontend_pct"
```

I guess this makes sense, because currently the `frontend_pct` table is empty, while the `frontend_item` has values in it.

Firstly, is the syntax of my `ALTER TABLE` correct?

Secondly, is there an automatic way to create the required values in `frontend_pct`? It would be great if there was some way to say to Postgres "create the foreign key, and insert values into the foreign key table if they don't exist".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax seems correct.

No, there is not an automatic way to insert the required values.

You can only do it manually before adding the constraint. In your case must be something like

```
INSERT INTO frontend_pct (code)
SELECT code FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT pct_code AS code
    FROM frontend_item
    WHERE pct_code NOT IN (SELECT code FROM frontend_pct)
) AS a;
```

**NOTICE:**

The query can be heavy if you have lot of data..